# Changing Scott Scale 960 2019/2020 rear hub to thru-axle?

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels, hub, through-axle

I'm interested to buy Scott Scale 960, but I would like to change rear hub from QR to 10 or 12mm thru-axle. Is it possible with or without changing rear hub? What kind of hub would it fit in case it would be needed to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're unlikely to get hubs that convert from QR to thru-axle as part of a complete factory bike, though a good number of after market hubs are available which can be swapped between the different standards using end caps. I say unlikely but it's not impossible, the best thing would be to contact Scott directly or your local dealer with the enquiry.

The problem you have though, is that the frame is designed around a QR axle. It has vertical dropouts, spaced 141 mm apart ([boost QR](https://www.scott-sports.com/gb/en/product/scott-scale-960-bike?article=274597008)) and no threads for a thru axle. Thru axles just don't fit in the same frames, so you can't fit a thru axle hub in the bike anyway.

*Unless*... it has been designed with this swap in mind, as Fred(tMWD) has commented previous models have featured. I'm inferring that Fred's was a premium model though.  Screenshot below of the current design of 960, looking to me like a traditional qr hanger design. In particular, the aluminium frame is inboard of the hanger, leading to a fixed geometry (O.L.D.), making me think this frame is designed with boost QR in mind only.

So again, unlikely on the frame being dual-compatible, but not for me to say impossible. An email to Scott could confirm.

[image]

Further reading on hubs: https://www.halowheels.com/frame-spacing-hub-o-l-d-information/

Comment: Agreed - OP is buying a brand new bike.  Since TA's are desired, that has to be part of the elimination criteria.   "buy the bike you want"

Comment: I'm not sure about that Scott, but a 2016 Scott Scale frame that I recently purchased came with the equivalent of "end caps" for the rear drop outs that would allow either QR or thru-axles. 960 is a low end Scott so that may not be available. From what I can see on the web it doesn't look to have the high end dropouts.

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog that's a really good point thanks, I've tried to incorporate that in.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and info. Looks like Scale 950 has TA, but not the 960, despite being said they are the same frames. And indeed it does not look like I could fit TA on 960 frame. 

I'll rather look for other brands of bikes with TA, because Scott reaches through my budget and price limit.